# Perform clustering from a similarity matrix

Tags: python, k-means

I have a list of songs for each of which I have extracted a feature vector. I calculated a similarity score between each vector and stored this in a similarity matrix. I would like to cluster the songs based on this similarity matrix to attempt to identify clusters or sort of genres.

I have used the `network_x` package to create a force-directed graph from the similarity matrix, using the spring layout. Then I used KMeans clustering on the position of the nodes from that graph and this resulted in clusters that made sense. However, I'm not sure that this is the correct approach as it is fundamentally linked with the positions given by the spring layout.

I have also attempted to run Spectral Clustering on the similarity matrix, however, it is too slow.

My question is this:

Is using the positions derived from a graph generated from the similarity matrix, and then using the spring layout piped into KMeans to extract clusters, fundamentally flawed? If so, what could be a potential alternative way to cluster elements given a similarity matrix?

Thanks

Comment: There are many different approaches to clustering, and which one to choose always depends on the specific problem and particularly on what meaning it has, in terms of the subject matter, to say that certain observations form a "cluster". E.g., there are approaches that attempt to find homogeneous clusters that are not necessarily well separated, and others that attempt to find well separated clusters but allow for heterogeneity (large within-cluster distances). These will normally lead to different clusterings, and the user needs to decide what they want. How big is your matrix?

Comment: In my case, I would like to find homogenous clusters that are not necessarily well separated. You can imagine my first approach as me trying to recreate some form of latent space of the songs by using network_x, and performing clustering on the positions of the points to achieve genre-like clusters. I have tens of thousands of songs, and thus my idea was to create the clustering for a few hundred and use the trained clustering model to assign a label to the rest. Do you think this is fundamentally flawed or is there a better way to get these genre-like clusters from the similarity matrix.

Comment: I don't know what network_x is. Anyway, if you're going to cluster up to, say, 3000 observations, Partitioning Around Medoids (PAM) should give you reasonably homogeneous clusters without any latent space embedding. The remaining songs can be pretty easily assigned to the resulting clusters. I'm not an expert on computational stuff, so there may be methods that are computationally more efficient for your size of a dataset, however I'd prefer clustering based on the similarities directly to embedding them in some latent space first, as this reduces information.